# Extracting RegEx pattern across list excluding other html code

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written a script to pull a list of available report url extensions page available for text extraction.

I've used parsing and BeautifulSoup to extract the reference area for the latest report using this method.

```
home = BeautifulSoup(home_url, 'html.parser')
container = home.find('div', attrs={'class': 'list'})
report_url_locations = list(x for x in container.findAll('a'))
```

This generates a list with each report and it's unique html extension, which is updated each time a new report is uploaded, for example:

```
[<a href="2022-05/13/c_76843.htm">May 16: Daily report</a>,
 <a href="2022-05/12/c_76842.htm">May 15: Daily report</a>,
 <a href="2022-05/11/c_76841.htm">May 14: Daily report</a>,
 <a href="2022-05/10/c_76839.htm">May 13: Daily report</a>]
```

I've managed to write some code to strip out html junk and keep just the extension for the first element (i.e. first report).

```
latest_sitrep_location = str(report_url_locations[0])
latest_sitrep_htm_location = re.search(r"[0-9]+-[0-9]+/[0-9]+/+c_[0-9]+.+htm",latest_sitrep_location)
```

This gives me:

```
"2022-05/13/c_76843.htm"
```

But when I try to do this for every element of the list it just throws me all the junk in-between:

```
all_urls= re.findall(r"[0-9]+-[0-9]+/[0-9]+/+c_[0-9]+.+htm", str(report_url_locations))
all_urls

['2022-05/13/c_76843.htm">May 16: Daily Report</a>, <a href="2022-05/12/c_76842.htm">May 15: Daily Report</a>, <a href="2022-05/11/c_76841.htm">May 14: Daily Report</a>, <a href="2022-05/10/c_76839.htm">May 13: Daily Report</a>]
```

But what I want is:

```
["2022-05/13/c_76843.htm","2022-05/12/c_76842.htm","2022-05/11/c_76841.htm","2022-05/10/c_76839.htm"]
```

Can somebody tell me what I need to include in my RegEx to ensure the other html is excluded? I'm fairly sure I need to convert every element in report_url_locations to be strings, but I don't know how to do this en-masse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just try this:

```
report_url_locations = [x["href"] for x in container.findAll('a')]
```

And then just print the `report_url_locations`

By the way, [here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not) you *shouldn't* be using `regex` to parse an HTML.

Comment: That was just as smooth as butter, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Don't use regex for HTML parsing, you know the drill.

If you're decided on using regex though, you could use `r'(?:href=)\"(.*?)\"'`.

```py
text="""<a href="2022-05/13/c_76843.htm">May 16: Daily report</a>,
 <a href="2022-05/12/c_76842.htm">May 15: Daily report</a>,
 <a href="2022-05/11/c_76841.htm">May 14: Daily report</a>,
 <a href="2022-05/10/c_76839.htm">May 13: Daily report</a>
"""

re.findall(r'(?:href=)\"(.*?)\"', text)
```

Which outputs

```
['2022-05/13/c_76843.htm',
 '2022-05/12/c_76842.htm',
 '2022-05/11/c_76841.htm',
 '2022-05/10/c_76839.htm']
```

Comment: Regex is a poor choice for HTML parsing. [Read this thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not).

Comment: I know I know, this is just for fun.

Comment: I'll add a disclaimer